Wix toolset: How to change the logo of msi in the task bar when it is executing
I wish to change the logo of my msi that i have created using wix toolset in the task bar when the user runs the msi installer.
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon" />
this changes the icon in the add/remove program in the control panel but i need to change the icon in the task bar i also tried searching about this but everywhere it says that the msi logo can not be changed, but i have seen some msi files that have changed the logo of their msi file while it is executing in the taskbar. is this possible using wix toolset without creating a bootstrap application, because we need this as a msi installer not  a exe file.

This is possible using a bootstrapper EXE. However, if you want it to work with a pure MSI file, you'll need to open a feature request with Microsoft to add support for it.
